# Which Task manager is most similar to the Mac OS task manager

Tags: applications, system

Is there a good task manager similar looking to the Mac OS one. I’ll link an image since I’m using the stack exchange app and it’s giving me errors when uploading a photo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how similar it is compared to the MAC OS one, but [Optimizer](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.hannesschulze.optimizer/) may have some of the Mac OS' task manager features. There is also [Monitor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.stsdc.monitor/) but it's pretty simplistic.